# How to uninstall OS from dual boot system?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uninstall

I have HDDs with different configurations of Windows and Ubuntu versions:

- Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7
- Ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 8
- Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10
  ...

I would like to uninstall Windows from some discs. 
I have also other OSs in some discs so it would be great if there exists some generic approach which leaves only one OS in the system i.e. Ubuntu. 
At the moment, I have replaced such systems by installing a fresh OS on top of them but it is inefficient because I lose everything there. 
I would like to maintain their content.

How can you uninstall Windows in some discs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download GParted

> sudo apt-get install gparted

From your Ubuntu delete or format the partitions on which your particular Windows is installed. (Every disk is shown by a letter. You have sda, sdb and sdc.)
After removing your Windows from the disks update your Grub

> sudo update-grub

That is it!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to keep Windows only, you could do something similar with EasyBCD updating your boot information.  Below is a link for configuring a dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu:

https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/linux/ubuntu/